# Angular Js Translation Partial Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, translation

I am binding translation.
The issue is , some object convert to translated value, while some like mentioned below didn't work. This issue happened only first time when I build project. On refresh it gets fine.
This is not happening to all html objects.

```
angular.module('App').factory('APILoader', ['localStorageService', '$http', '$q', function (localStorageService, $http, $q) {
        var translationAPIUrl = "Translation/Get";

        return function (options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(translationAPIUrl, { params: { id: culture } }).success(function (response) {
                    data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                }).error(function (data) {
                        deferred.reject(options.key);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;

        };
    }]);
```

Html:

```
<b> {{('Heading' |translate)}}</b>
```

Comment: Is that a custom filter or do you use a 3th party library? If it is custom, can you add that code as well?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @JustusRomijn Seems like angular-translate.

Comment: I am using this: http://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate
No Error because it happened to some objects only

Comment: And you set that factory as a loader by using `$translateProvider.useLoader('APILoader')`?

Comment: Yes,
By the way,l have convert api controller to mvc controller due to addition of outputcache
Is it the possible issue, that I am using mvc controller "Translation/Get"?

Comment: I just reset it to API Controller, and it worked fine.
Why is it so? Can anyone explain

Answer (score 0):

I got it. 
The issue is with deferred, 
It did not resolve properly and get return.
The Key line is:

```
deferred.promise.then(function () {});
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
angular.module('App').factory('APILoader', ['localStorageService', '$http', '$q', function (localStorageService, $http, $q) {
    var translationAPIUrl = "Translation/Get";

    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(translationAPIUrl, { params: { id: culture } }).success(function (response) {
                data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
                deferred.promise.then(function () {});
                });
            }).error(function (data) {
                    deferred.reject(options.key);
                });
            return deferred.promise;

    };
}]);
```